# How to make dropdown element read-only

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //$('#notes_edit_1').hide();
    $('#notes_edit_1').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

If I use `.hide()` **it works**, however disabled/hide does not work.

I've also tried `.prop('disabled', true);`

I've even tried .prop('readonly',true);

Basically I need the element to be viewed but not click-able.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try $('#notes_edit_1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

Comment: can you please post your HTML code

Comment: but it is working for me http://jsfiddle.net/8m4Tj/33/

Comment: Your code works here. **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/989w2/)**

Comment: if on page load you are disabling the dropdown. then why don't you add disabled in html code?
Why you need jquery to handle it.

Comment: Here's the HTML snip

<a href="index.php?module=Notes&amp;action=EditView&amp;record=204c370a-eca3-11e3-8948-ba377517220c&amp;parent_module=Leads&amp;parent_id=475093000000245011&amp;return_module=Leads&amp;return_id=475093000000245011&amp;return_action=DetailView&amp;return_relationship=notes" onmouseover="subp_nav('Notes', '204c370a-eca3-11e3-8948-ba377517220c', 'e', this, 'notes');" onfocus="subp_nav('Notes', '204c370a-eca3-11e3-8948-ba377517220c', 'e', this, 'notes');" class="listViewTdToolsS1" id="notes_edit_1" disabled="disabled">edit</a>

Comment: you cannot disable a link..

Comment: @user3218823 check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24160818/829533

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `$('#notes_edit_1')` is a link you need to make it non clickable, disabled is not a valid `a` tag attribute

```
 <a href="index.php?module=Notes&amp;action=EditView&amp;record=204c370a-eca3-11e3-8‌​948-ba377517220c&amp;parent_module=Leads&amp;parent_id=475093000000245011&amp;ret‌​urn_module=Leads&amp;return_id=475093000000245011&amp;return_action=DetailView&am‌​p;return_relationship=notes" onmouseover="subp_nav('Notes', '204c370a-eca3-11e3-8948-ba377517220c', 'e', this, 'notes');" onfocus="subp_nav('Notes', '204c370a-eca3-11e3-8948-ba377517220c', 'e', this, 'notes');" class="listViewTdToolsS1" id="notes_edit_1" disabled="disabled">edit</a>
```

in your javascript

```
$('#notes_edit_1').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

they are different things

```
$('#notes_edit_1').hide();
```

it will hide your `$('#notes_edit_1')` and will not be visible at browser

```
$('#notes_edit_1').attr('disabled', true);
```

and it will set its `disabled` attribute to true and you cannot use/change it, only if its a form element. also it wont be post to the server. So yes it will be hidden from the server but not from your browser.

if you want you element to be visible but non clickable/changeable

and you want your code to post data to server make it readonly

```
$('#notes_edit_1').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

and if you want your code to not to post data to server make it disabled

```
$('#notes_edit_1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

just add option after your id in code
Try this

```
  $('#notes_edit_1 option').attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: you told in your question "How to make dropdown element read-only? " if you ask that how we can disable link.then my answer would be different.

Comment: My apologies, I guess I framed my question wrongly.

Comment: its ok .... :)  ..yes,your question is wrong,actually you wanted to disable link...you found solution ..thats gud ....leave it...you can upvote now my answer......@ user3218823